# Django error SiteProfileNotAvailable

Tags: python, django, django-users

Im installed django-userena with django 1.9.7,
https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena
step by step ,why I'm I getting this error?

Thanks
settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'userena',
'guardian',
'easy_thumbnails',
]
ANONYMOUS_USER_ID = -1
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",       line 353, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
django.setup()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 115, in populate
app_config.ready()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 22, in ready
self.module.autodiscover()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
__import__(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\userena\admin.py", line 31, in <module>
admin.site.register(get_profile_model(), GuardedModelAdmin)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\userena\utils.py", line 137, in get_profile_model
raise SiteProfileNotAvailable
userena.compat.SiteProfileNotAvailable
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [docs](http://django-userena.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#id2) you need to create a Site object (see [Sites Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/)) either from admin panel or shell or via fixture and define its ID in settings using `SITE_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `INSTALLED_APPS` contains the `accounts` app which in its models needs to contain the custom Profile model. See also https://django-userena-ce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#start-new-app